# How to add material UI theme to React Table?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table, material-design

I have a table implemented using React Table(https://react-table.js.org) 
Functionality wise its fast and displays data, but it has its own default styling.
I want to implement Material design theme on it. What is the way to it? Should I include a CSS file?

Comment: You will have to override the styles of React Table and apply the styles of Material-UI table.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out / write the css yourself?